# Dynamically including/excluding fields from Meta class of a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms

Let's say I have a form such as:

```py
from django import forms

class Foo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

How can I include or exclude fields based on some condition?

Edit:

My bad, I should have clarified that the condition needs to be made based on a value on each model that is being rendered. That means that I need to add (or remove) fields based on the values of the model that is currently being rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify form fields via **`__init__`**:

```
from django import forms

class Foo(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if condition:
            self.fields.pop('field1')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Note that this can cause the form's validation to fail if the field is required.

A better approach might be to hide the field, instead of removing it entirely:

```
class Foo(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if condition:
            form.fields['field1'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Comment: Let me try that!

Comment: Yes, that's definitively what I was looking for :)